# merge multiple rows by average based on time range on a day

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe which has 3 columns **Date , Time , Value**

---

```
**Date**    **Time**   **Value**
7/1/1990    0:00:00       10
7/1/1990    1:00:00       10       
7/1/1990    1:15:00       12
7/1/1990    1:50:00       11
7/1/1990    2:00:00       10
7/1/1990    3:00:00       10
7/1/1990    3:30:00       12
7/1/1990    4:00:00       11
....
8/1/1990    0:00:00       11
8/1/1990    1:00:00       12       
8/1/1990    2:00:00       11
8/1/1990    2:50:00       11
8/1/1990    3:00:00       12
8/1/1990    4:00:00       10
8/1/1990    4:30:00       12
.....
```

I want to merge all rows by taking average for time frame like 0:00:00 to 0:59:59 or 4:00:00 to 4:59:59

---

```
**Date**    **Time**   **Value**
7/1/1990    0:00:00       10
7/1/1990    1:00:00       11       
7/1/1990    2:00:00       10
7/1/1990    3:00:00       11
7/1/1990    4:00:00       11
....
8/1/1990    0:00:00       11
8/1/1990    1:00:00       12       
8/1/1990    2:00:00       11
8/1/1990    3:00:00       12
8/1/1990    4:00:00       11
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pandas.to_datetime` and `pandas.DataFrame.resample`:

```
import pandas as pd

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df[['Date', 'Time']].apply(' '.join, 1), dayfirst=True)
new_df = df.resample('1H').mean().dropna().reset_index()
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
                index  Value
0 1990-01-07 00:00:00   10.0
1 1990-01-07 01:00:00   11.0
2 1990-01-07 02:00:00   10.0
3 1990-01-07 03:00:00   11.0
4 1990-01-07 04:00:00   11.0
5 1990-01-08 00:00:00   11.0
6 1990-01-08 01:00:00   12.0
7 1990-01-08 02:00:00   11.0
8 1990-01-08 03:00:00   12.0
9 1990-01-08 04:00:00   11.0
```